# jquery prompted variable value given to python script

Tags: javascript, python

I have what I think to be a simple problem, but I cannot figure out the solution. I have a javascript form with options, and when the user selects an option they get prompted to input a value as below:

```
var integer_value = window.prompt("What is the integer value?", "defaultText")
```

I then need this integer value to be used by a python script. So, if say in my python script:

```
integer_value = 2
```

It would need to change to whatever value the user inputs in the prompt window.

Comment: So you have a Web server that's serving an HTML page which uses JavaScript to get an integer, and you want to know how to send that integer to a Python CGI script running on the same server. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, except that I am not using CGI. In a previous question I asked, the python script is only creating a .txt file. So, when the integer_value changes the .txt file will also change. I just need the JavaScript to send this new integer_value to the python script.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but it's possible to do simple CGI stuff without using CGI libraries. I don't know Ajax, or jQuery, but I do know "plain" JavaScript. And I can show you how to send data from a JavaScript function in your Web page to a Python script, using basic CGI techniques. But why do you want to send the data from a prompt? Is there some reason you can't use a form?

Comment: edit to OP. I am using a form, when they select an option then they get prompted. Sorry for confusion. I need to send the data from the prompt because my python script creates a txt file that is then used for display features.

Comment: So does that mean you want the data sent to the server from the prompt _before_ the form itself is submitted? Or would it be ok if the integer_value data got sent to the server with the rest of the form data?

Comment: It would be fine if the integer_value data got sent with the rest of the form data yes.

Comment: Ok. How are you receiving the form data? Is that being done by your python script that creates the txt file? Or is the form data being received by a separate program, which then runs the txt file creation script?

Comment: I probably should have included this in the OP. I am using flask. When the user is prompted I need integer_value to go to a separate python program that creates the .txt file. Flask then opens this python program and the .txt file is created. I just need to send the variable to the python program. Sorry for all of the confusion.

Comment: You probably should've put a Flask tag into your question; it seems pretty popular on SO. If you put all the relevant info into your questions they're *much* more likely to get a response. I don't know Flask, but I'll throw together some example code that *should* work for you and post it shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below *should* do what you need. There may be better ways to do this, but at least this way is fairly simple.

Next time you have a Web programming question, tell us what server you're using, and what framework, and any JavaScript things like jQuery or Ajax. And post a *small* working demo of your code, both the HTML/JavaScript and the Python, that we can actually run so we can see exactly what you're talking about.

Firstly, here's a small HTML/JavaScript page that prompts the user for data and sends it to the server.

**send_to_python.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Send data to Python demo</title>

<script>
function get_and_send_int()
{
    var s, integer_value, default_value = 42;
    s = window.prompt("What is the integer value?", default_value);
    if (s==null || s=='')
    {
        alert('Cancelled');
        return;
    }

    //Check that the data is an integer before sending
    integer_value = parseInt(s);
    if (integer_value !== +s)
    {
        alert(s + ' is not an integer, try again');
        return;
    }

    //Send it as if it were a GET request.
    location.href = "cgi-bin/save_js_data.py?data=" + integer_value;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h4>"Send data to Python" demo</h4>
<p>This page uses JavaScript to get integer data from the user via a prompt<br>
and then sends the data to a Python script on the server.</p>

<p>Click this button to enter the integer input and send it.<br>
<input type="button" value="get &amp; send" onclick="get_and_send_int()">
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And now for the CGI Python program that receives the data and logs it to a file. A proper program would have some error checking & data validation, and a way of reporting any errors. The Python CGI module would make this task a little easier, but it's not strictly necessary.

The Web server normally looks for CGI programs in a directory called cgi-bin, and that's generally used as the program's Current Working Directory. A CGI program doesn't run in a normal terminal: its stdin and stdout are essentially connected to the Web page that invoked the program, so anything it prints gets sent back to the Web page. And (depending on the request method used) it may receive data from the page via stdin.

The program below doesn't read stdin (and will appear to hang if you try). The data is sent to it as part of the URL used to invoke the program, and the server extracts that data and puts it into an environment variable that the CGI program can access.

**save_js_data.py**

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' save_js_data

    A simple CGI script to receive data from "send_to_python.html" 
    and log it to a file
'''

import sys, os, time

#MUST use CRLF in HTTP headers
CRLF = '\r\n'

#Name of the file to save the data to.
outfile = 'outfile.txt'

def main():
    #Get the data that was sent from the Web page
    query = os.environ['QUERY_STRING']

    #Get the number out of QUERY_STRING
    key, val = query.split('=')
    if key == 'data':
        #We really should check that val contains a valid integer

        #Save the current time and the received data to outfile
        s = '%s, %s\n' % (time.ctime(), val)
        with open(outfile, 'a+t') as f:
            f.write(s)

    #Send browser back to the refering Web page
    href = os.environ['HTTP_REFERER']
    s = 'Content-type: text/html' + CRLF * 2
    s += '<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=%s">' % href
    print s


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When you save this program to your hard drive, make sure that you give it execute permissions. Since you're using Flask, I assume your server is configured to run Python CGI programs and that you know what directory it looks in for such programs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response and for all of your help, I'll try your answer now and get back to you.

Comment: That's ok. Your question motivated me to brush up my CGI skills; I haven't played with this stuff for 3 or 4 years.